# JS: Edge case issue - replacing variable in array

Tags: javascript, arrays

Programming test is coming back with an edge case failure:

**Empty array - Expected: [], instead got: [""]**

**Brief:**
The Western Suburbs Croquet Club has two categories of membership, Senior and Open. They would like your help with an application form that will tell prospective members which category they will be placed.

To be a senior, a member must be at least 55 years old and have a handicap greater than 7. In this croquet club, handicaps range from -2 to +26; the better the player the lower the handicap.

**Input**

Input will consist of a list of lists containing two items each. Each list contains information for a single potential member. Information consists of an integer for the person's age and an integer for the person's handicap.

**Example Input:**

```
[[18, 20],[45, 2],[61, 12],[37, 6],[21, 21],[78, 9]]
```

**Output**

Output will consist of a list of string values (in Haskell: Open or Senior) stating whether the respective member is to be placed in the senior or open category.

**Example Output**
["Open", "Open", "Senior", "Open", "Open", "Senior"]

**My function:**

```
function openOrSenior(data){
  var c = [];
  var i;

  for (i = 0; i < data.length; ++i) {
    var person = data[i];
    var age = person[0];
    var handicap = person[1];

    // senior
    if ((age >= 55) && (handicap > 7))  {
      person = [];
      person.push("Senior");
    } else {
      person = [];
      person.push("Open");
    }

    c.push(person);
  }

  return c.join().split(',');
}
```

Any pointers?

Comment: What that `return c.join().split(',');` is for?

Comment: @c-smile I think OP is getting confused by the `,` in the output example, not realizing that they are just part of how the array is being displayed, not actual data.

Comment: Why are you pushing **arrays** into `c`? Not just strings? Your example output shows strings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason is

1. You're pushing *arrays* onto `c`, rather than just strings
2. Then you're doing `c.join().split(',')`, which will first combine those arrays into a string (in a fairly subtle way), and then split that string on a delimiter (`','`). The result of `split` is **always** at least one entry long — if the array has no occurrences of the delimiter (which it won't if `c` is empty at the outset), you get back an array with a single string in it (a blank one, if `c` is empty at the outset).

E.g., `[].toString().split(",")` is `[""]`, not `[]`.

The solution is to push strings, not arrays, into `c` and then return it directly (no `.join().split(',')`).

---

About my "fairly subtle way" comment above. If you have an array of arrays, like this:

```
var a = [ ["a", "b"], ["c", "d"], ["e", "f"] ];
```

`a.join()` will loop through every entry in `a` and call `toString` on it. Since the entries in `a` are arrays, calling `toString` on them is the same as calling `join` (it's just how `Array#toString` is defined), so you end up doing `['a', 'b'].toString()`, which gives you `"a,b"`, then the same with the second entry (`"c,d"`), then again with the third (`"e,f"`), and then taking all of those and making a single string out of them, with commas in-between (`"a,b,c,d,e,f"`).

Comment: @HarryL: Right, which as you can see returns the correct result when `data` is empty: https://jsfiddle.net/2xedzf4g/1/  Side note: Look at the [`Array#map` function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map), it would make the code simpler and more concise.

Comment: Gotcha! Something like --> https://jsfiddle.net/2xedzf4g/2/ - ps. totally can't take credit for this. CodeWars 'clever' solution! Thought you might like to see it.

Comment: @HarryL: Right. Or https://jsfiddle.net/2xedzf4g/4/ as there's really no need for the separate declaration, and the `()` around the condition in the conditional operator are completely unnecessary. Or https://jsfiddle.net/2xedzf4g/5/ on an ES2015- (ES6-) enabled JavaScript engine.

Answer (score -1):

Try the following:

```
function openOrSenior(data){
  function determineMembership(member){
    return (member[0] >= 55 && member[1] > 7) ? 'Senior' : 'Open';
  }
  return data.map(determineMembership);
}
```